# .htaccess create Error 500

Tags: .htaccess

I have these entries in .htaccess:

```xml
<FilesMatch "\.(txt)$">
 AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Authentication required"
  AuthUserFile .htpasswd
  require adelein
</FilesMatch>
```

With this in .htpasswd:

```
adelein:$apr1$cs4ixtev$kqAo2aH1VgZR9mbo.RnH80
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The User:Pass Dialog will not appear!

Comment: Remove the **require..** line it is an invalid command to the server, also you are using password protection inside filesmatch, password dialog will apper for .txt files only.

Comment: No function, also without require

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: Error 500 server error

Comment: Can you edit your question to post the full htaccess?

Comment: It is the full htaccess

Comment: Are you sure the error is 500 "internal server error" ? after removing the require line the code is working fine on my apache server. Password dialog appears when I go to **foo.txt**

Comment: Can you give me your dir and filestructure please

Comment: We have the same problem that you have. What is the problem? :-)

Comment: Oh my god! I have the mistake! I must save the file as ASCII. I have saved it before as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for requiring a user should be

```
require user adeleine
```